# Does a builder count as a follower when scoring?

Tags: carcassonne

The rules say  you can have more than one builder on a road or in a city, so what happens when a city is completed and it has a follower and builder of one person and a big follower and builder of another person? Does the builder count as a follower or do you only count the other normal followers?

Answer (score 8):

**Builders (and Pigs) are not followers and are not counted when calculating a majority.**

In your case, the city would be scored for the owner of the big follower.

Originally, builders and pigs were followers but this was changed a while back.  Rio Grande Games adopted this rule upon the release of the Big Box Edition.

Comment: Before that, even... I bought T&B before the big box was released, and the builder and pig didn't count towards victory on a given feature.